# How to enforce MUI styling, if it is being overwritten by a global setting?

Tags: material-ui

I am working on a React Component, something like a Quiz, that will be inserted into a client's webpage. I obviously don't have any say in their website's stylesheet and can't do anything about it, it is what it is. So I am wondering if there is a way to enforce the Material UI on MUI components?

**Examples:**

[image]
This is my development build.

[image]
And this is inside the production build, on my client's website. They have a  global setting, that is overwriting this one. Specifically they are targeting `input[type="email"]`, which is causing me troubles.

So I am asking here if there is a way for it to enforce MUI styling.

Comment: can it be changed to `input[type="email"]:not([class^="Mui"])`?

Comment: No, I don't have access to their styling.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `className` props to your `Material UI` inputs let's say `className="email-input"` then create a `css` file add that className and to add to it the height, width and other styles you want, just like how you would do styling in normal `html` file then import it in your react component file.

When you add your project to your client's site the `css` file will be loaded after their site's `css`, so your styles will override theirs.

Comment: That just creates my own style! But I want to enforce the MUI style that already there is. The other alternative would be to just copy and paste the MUI styling into a new className, but I want to know if I can just enforce MUI styling. After all I don't want new styling.

Comment: You can add `!important` emphasis on your `Material UI` styles like this:
```javascript
emailInput: {
  display: "block",
  height: "36px !important",
  width: "100% !important",
}
```